# In Python, df.head() prints csv file twice

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
df=pd.read_csv("cricket.csv")
print(df.head())
```

[image]

Comment: show `cat seaborn.py` and try by changing the file name.

Comment: comment or remove import seaborn as sns part from your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script is called `seaborn.py` and inside this script you `import seaborn`, the script is imported into itself and hence run twice (once at import, then for the rest of the lines).

Best solution (and general advice): **Never call a script by the same name as a module you want to import.**